# Django exclude a single url from adding slash

Tags: django, django-urls

I've added 2 views to my Django urls config for SEO but when I view them on my site it redirects them to the url I setup but with an added slash. I know Django likes to tidy up URLs with a slash (and I like this) but is there a way to exclude a single url or a few urls from this feature?

```
    ...
    url(r'^robots\.txt/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),

    url(r'^sitemap\.xml/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sitemap.xml', content_type='text/xml')),
    ...
```

These append slash to the urls resulting in `robots.txt/` and `sitemap.xml/` not `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`

Comment: Looking at the source of [CommonMiddleware:should_redirect_with_slash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/middleware/common/#CommonMiddleware) if your url without a slash will be a valid one, it should not redirect to one with slash - did you try to remove the slash before the `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want slashes at the end of `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`, then simply remove the trailing slashes from those regexes.

```
url(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='sitemap.xml', content_type='text/xml')),
```

The URLs `/robots.txt` and `/sitemap.xml` will then match, and Django will not append the slash.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that. Thanks for saving my sanity!